# Vuex: Trying to run a block of code in a Getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a getters:

```
getVipCustomersKeys(state) {
    if (state.vipCustomers) {
        let arr = [];
        for (x in state.vipCustomers) {
            arr.push(x);
        }
    }
    return arr;
},
```

When I inspect the getter in Vue Tools, it shows `getVipCustomersKeys: x is not defined`.  How can I accomplish this within the getter?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using an implicit global `x` where you should define it locally.

You should also define `arr` outside the `if` block.

```js
getVipCustomersKeys(state) {
  const arr = [] // define "arr" before the "if"
  if (state.vipCustomers) {
    for (let x in state.vipCustomers) { // define "x" locally
      arr.push(x);
    }
  }
  return arr;
},
```

---

Even better, just use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return all the keys from `state.vipCustomers`

```js
getVipCustomersKeys: ({ vipCustomers }) => Object.keys(vipCustomers ?? {})
```